# What is the diffrence between diamond and circular breakpoints in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, breakpoints

Today when I was working like every day I have noticed something odd in the android studio. The 2 kinds of breakpoints I have never seen it before. I want to know what is the differences and why?

[image: The picture of breakpoints.]

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

copied from [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#)

a circular breakpoint is a line breakpoint, while a diamond breakpoint is a method breakpoint.

Line breakpoints: suspend the program upon reaching the line of code where the breakpoint was set. This type of breakpoints can be set on any executable line of code.

Method breakpoints: suspend the program upon entering or exiting the specified method or one of its implementations, allowing you to check the method's entry/exit conditions.

for more info about breakpoints and their types check this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-types)